# jQuery nth-child selector issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I need to hide some columns of an html table using jQuery. I'm using the below code:

```
$('#my-table tr td:nth-child(7),th:nth-child(7)').hide()
```

The code is working, it's hiding the column of the table, however is not respecting the table id selector, it's applying the change for all the tables in the current document.

What should I change in order to have it working as expected?

Comment: `$('#my-table tr td:nth-child(7), #my-table th:nth-child(7)')` - you have to declare the outer ID each time, it can't guess that's what you mean

Comment: The comment above is most likely your issue. You missed the ID on the second selector

Comment: Thanks, it's working now! @DarrenSweeney

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the `id` for both selectors, otherwise the `th:nth-child(7)` it will hide **every** `th:nth-child(7)` you might have in your code

```
$('#my-table tr td:nth-child(7), #my-table th:nth-child(7)').hide()
```

You can also simplify this by using the  [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method

```
$('#my-table tr').find('td:nth-child(7), th:nth-child(7)').hide()
```

**EDIT**

as pointed out by [@A. Wolff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff) this can be even more simplified using just this:

```
$('#my-table tr > :nth-child(7)').hide()
```

Comment: Thanks!, this is the same answer that Darren has provided above. Since this this the first answer to the question, I will accept it as correct in 5 more minutes. Sorry, the SO time restriction.

Comment: Wouldn't that be enough: `$('#my-table tr :nth-child(7)').hide()`?!  Because the child of `tr` can only be `td` or `th` (or `template` but it isn't displayed anyway)

Comment: @A.Wolff yes it would, I', gonna add it to my answer thanks.

Comment: I edited to add the children selector to make it even more robust because we don't know what can contains `td` :)

Comment: @A.Wolff makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [comma separated multiple selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) but it should be the complete selector.

```
$('#my-table tr td:nth-child(7),#my-table th:nth-child(7)')
```

or **[`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** method with multiple inner element selector

```
$('#my-table tr').find('td:nth-child(7),th:nth-child(7)')
```